# Tikz drawing with function

Tags: tikz-pgf

I wanna know a clear way to code the function while drawing with it, for ex. how to write this `f(x)= -(x+1)(x-2)(x-4)`

how to code it in the below command?

```
\draw [red,ultra thick,domain=-1:2,samples=400,latex-latex] plot (\x,---);
```

Please there is any clear coding way for these cases?

i tried but it in -5(x + 3)(x-1)(x-2)(x-7) but it didn't work

please wanna coding way for the functions like sin(x) or tan(x)

Comment: Please have a look at the `pgfplots` package. I guess that you are a total beginner. In that case, I recommend reading an introduction to LaTex first (I recommend a recent book).

Comment: @MarwaHashem is your question solved? Would you accept an answer?

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[very thin,color=black] (-0,-0) grid (4,4);

\draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (4.2,0) node[right] {$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.2) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$f(x)$};

\draw[blue] (0,0) plot[domain=2:4] (\x,{-(\x+1)*(\x-2)*(\x-4)}) node[anchor=south west] {$V_{p}$};


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried but it in -5(x + 3)(x-1)(x-2)(x-7) but it didn't work

Comment: @MarwaHashem You need to have `*` between them to express multiplication, i.e. `-5*(x+3)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-7)`.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way using pgfplots for your function -5(x + 3)(x-1)(x-2)(x-7):

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        domain     = -5:8,
        ymin       = -2000,
        ymax       =  2000,
        samples    = 50,
        axis lines = middle
      ]
    \addplot [mark = none, color = blue]
      {-5*(x + 3)*(x-1)*(x-2)*(x-7)};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot]